# What is the correct architecture for convolutional neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolution, deep-learning

I have seen several different architectures for convolutional neural network (CNN). I am confused which one is the standard and how do I decide what to use. I am not confused by the number of layers being used or the number of parameters involved; I am confused by the COMPONENTS of the network.

Let assume:

CL = convolution layer SL = subsampling layer(pooling) CM = convolution map NN = neural network Softmax = softmax classifier (similar to linear classifier)

1. Architecture 1
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6hpQwq7Inw

   CL,SL,CL,SL,CM,Softmax
2. Architecture 2 (Do we really need NN at the end again?)
   http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5605630&tag=1

   CL,SL,CL, SL, NN, Softmax
3. Architecture 3
   My idea

   CL, SL, CL, SL, Softmax

Answer (score 4):

There's no single one-size-suit-all CNN architecture. CNNs are usually designed to efficiently capture features of input data. It's assumed that these features are hierarchical, i.e. high-level features are made of low-level ones. CNN is just fancy feature extraction algorithm, you can put any classifier you want on top of it (NN, Softmax, whatever).

So convolutional layers are used to extract features from input. Subsampling layers, then, downscale the image in order to reduce computation complexity and make it shift-invariant.

Convolution map layer isn't that different from usual convolutional layer, I'm not sure if it's common to make this distinction. Actually, if you want to deal with color information, your input (to the first conv. layer) would be not a single image, but several (3, for example) images, each being a separate feature map.

What classifier to use on top of CNN is completely up to you. You can use Logistic Regression, SVM, NN or any other classification (or regression) algorithm.